# Error while deserializing xml string into object using XMLSerializer in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

Here is my DTO

```
[XmlTypeAttribute(TypeName="XAttributes")]
public class XAttributes
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName="Attributes")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName="Attribute")]
    public List<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }    
    public XAttributes()
    {
        Attributes = new List<Attribute>();
    }
}
public class Attribute
{      
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }      

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ValueType")]
    public ValueType ValueType {get; set; }

    [XmlArray(ElementName="Children" )]
    public List<Attribute> Children { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my deserializing code

```
  public static T ToObject<T>(this string XMLData)
    {
        var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        object obj=null;
        using (var sr = new StringReader(XMLData))
        {
            obj = s.Deserialize(sr);
        }
        return (T)obj;
    }
```

and here is the code i call to deserialize it

```
string attr = @"<XAttributes><Attributes>                          
                        <Attribute>
                        <Name>Test</Name>
                        <Value>TestVlau</Value>
                        <ValueType>STRING</ValueType>
                        <Children/>
                        </Attribute>
                        <Attribute>
                        <Name>Test1</Name>
                        <Value>TestVlau1</Value>
                        <ValueType>STRING</ValueType>
                        <Children/>
                        </Attribute>
                        </Attributes><XAttributes>";

        var attribute = attr.ToObject<XAttributes>();
```

i get error as

```
There is an error in XML document (14, 55).
```

at the line

```
 obj = s.Deserialize(sr);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Check the InnerException of the exception - it will give you the *real* problem.

Comment: Are you missing the closing '/' for XAttributes?

Comment: yes, @user959729 . you are right. my bad. thanks for finding me that issue. my bad i did not check the innerexception.

Comment: @AlagesanPalani It happens, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell here is the problem but try the following.... Replace

```
[XmlTypeAttribute(TypeName="XAttributes")]
public class XAttributes 
{
    ....
}
```

with this:

```
[XmlRoot("XAttributes")]
public class XAttributes 
{
    ....
}
```

Also, don't forget to include the XML declaration in your XML string:

```
string attr = @"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <XAttributes><Attributes>                          
        <Attribute>
        <Name>Test</Name>
        <Value>TestVlau</Value>
        <ValueType>STRING</ValueType>
        <Children/>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute>
        <Name>Test1</Name>
        <Value>TestVlau1</Value>
        <ValueType>STRING</ValueType>
        <Children/>
        </Attribute>
        </Attributes><XAttributes>";
```

PS: I have created a generic XmlSerializer that may be useful, please take a look at my article in CodeProject:

[XML serialization using Generics](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233908/Xml-serialization-using-generics)

Comment: thanks for your reply. As mentioned in the other comment i missed the closed / for XAttributes. it works fine now.